# PUT method not working in Postman 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#

In Postman, I get "The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax."

My API runs when I go to test it but I keep getting a 400 error when sending the PUT in Postman.

```
    [HttpPut("{status}")]
    [Route ("status")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateIntervention(string status, Intervention intervention)
    {
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (intervention.status == "Pending")
        {

            intervention.status = "InProgress";
            intervention.start_date = DateTime.Now;
            intervention.result = "Begun Maintenance";
            _context.interventions.Update(intervention);
            
        } else if (intervention.status == "InProgress") {

            intervention.status = "Completed";
            intervention.start_date = DateTime.Now;
            intervention.result = "Problem Solved";
            _context.interventions.Update(intervention);
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
          

        return NoContent();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

have to fix action, don't use status twice, and add frombody attribute. Also check Content-Type  in Postman, it should be 'application/json'.

```
[HttpPut("{status}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateIntervention(string status,[FromBody] Intervention intervention)

//or 
[HttpPut]
[Route("{status}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateIntervention(string status,[FromBody] Intervention intervention)
```

but it is better to use the a full route to avoid overlaping

```
[HttpPut("~/..controller name../UpdateIntervention/{status}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateIntervention(string status,[FromBody] Intervention intervention)
```

in this case your url should be too

```
http.../..controller name../UpdateIntervention/{status}
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the adjustments but now I'm getting "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

RestApi.Controllers.InterventionsController.PutIntervention (RestApi)
RestApi.Controllers.InterventionsController.UpdateIntervention (RestApi)"

Comment: @preston17 I updated my answer, replace ..controllername.. with  your real controller name

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to change `Content-Type` for your request in Postman.

`Content-Type` comes to the server as a header. In Postman it is set:

1. via the Headers tab OR
2. automatically, if you select the appropriate type in the `Body` Tab.

Most likely the value you need is 'application/json'.

Comment: What are you referring to? The route that I put in my postman before I hit send?

Comment: Content type is an http header you'd send with the request.

Comment: Where in my code would I change that?

Comment: You change this in postman, not in your code.

Comment: I have it set to json

Comment: the error it's giving me when i run it is "The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax." Does the syntax in my method seem to have any errors?

Comment: You need to be precise, did you set it to 'json' or 'application/json'. The error about syntax is about the payload, not your code.

Comment: Yeah i have it set to application/json

Comment: The request has to be in the format that the server is expecting.  Best way of debugging is to look up the documentation or the server or debug the code in the server to see what is causing error.  The connection is completing and while the server is processing the request a failure is occurring.